# What is included by default in Python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7, command-line

I need to know what libraries are included in Python 2.7.12.  The host provider we use, will not install pip so I can't use pip list to see what is available.  What command can I use from linux command line to see what is included in Python 2.7.12?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

1. start python from the console

```
2. help("modules")
```

A draw back is that it will take a little bit more time, but it should do the work.